# Sqlalchemy mock return value with join table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking

If I want to mock a return value of sqlalchemy table `Assignment`, I'll do the following way.

```
def get_all_assignments():
    return db.session.query(Assignment).all()


@patch('get_all_assignments')
def test_get_all_assignments(get_all_assignments_mock):
    get_all_assignments_mock.return_value = [
        Assignment(id=1)
    ]
    
    assignments = get_all_assignments()
    assert len(assignments) == 1
    assert assignments[0].id == 1
```

How to mock if the function involved with another table? EX:

```
def get_all_assignments_with_teacher():
    return db.session.query(Assignment, Teacher).join(Assignment.teacher).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered, I'll just share my solution.

We can utilize `magicmock` to do the trick.

```
@patch('get_all_assignments_with_teacher')
def test_get_all_assignments_with_teacher(get_all_assignments_with_teacher_mock):
    mock = MagicMock
    mock.Assignment = Assignment(id=1)
    mock.Teacher = Teacher(id=1)
    get_all_assignments_with_teacher_mock = [mock]
```